# c# Cannot convert anonymous type decimal? [] to decimal array

Tags: c#

I am have implemented a c# linq expression which returns a decimal nullable array. I basically need to pass it to a function that accepts decimal array

I am getting error

> Cannot convert anonymous type decimal? [] to decimal array.

```
var benchMark1Returns = GetViewService<MV_INDEX_PERFORMANCE>()
    .Where(x => x.IndexId == benchMark1 && x.PriceDate.Year == year)
    .Select(x => new { x.Mtd}).ToArray();

var benchMark2Returns = GetViewService<MV_INDEX_PERFORMANCE>()
    .Where(x => x.IndexId == benchMark2 && x.PriceDate.Year == year)
    .Select(x => new { x.Mtd }).ToArray();

var compoundReturnsBenchMark1 = CompoundReturns(benchMark1Returns);
```

The method that accepts decimal array

```
public static decimal? CompoundReturns(decimal[] rtns)
{
    if (rtns.Length == 0)
        return null;

    return rtns.Aggregate((decimal)1, (acc, val) => acc * (1 + val)) - 1;
}
```

Comment: Assuming `x.Mtd` is decimal, then just remove the `new {}` i.e. `(x => x.Mtd).ToArray()`

Answer (score 4):

First, you don't want a collection of an anonymous type:

```
.Select(x => new { x.Mtd })
```

You just want the decimal:

```
.Select(x => x.Mtd)
```

But furthermore, it's also telling you that `Mtd` is a `decimal?`, not a `decimal`.  The former can not be directly converted to the latter because the former supports values the latter does not.  (i.e. `null`)

So either you'll need to define a default value when `Mtd` is `null`:

```
.Select(x => x.Mtd ?? 0M)
```

or change your method to accept a `decimal?[]`:

```
public static decimal? CompoundReturns(decimal?[] rtns)
```

Note that in that last case you will also need to update your method to support a `null` value.  For example, changing the type to which you case `1` in the `Aggregate()` call:

```
rtns.Aggregate((decimal?)1, (acc, val) => acc * (1 + val)) - 1;
```

Comment: If I change the method to accept decimal? then I get error at this line of code   return rtns.Aggregate((decimal)1, (acc, val) => acc * (1 + val)) - 1; cannot convert decimal? to decimal

Comment: @Tom: So you're going to need to decide whether you want to support `null` values or not.  If you want to, all of the code will have to support them.  Do you want to support `null` values?

Comment: Bascially while commuting compoundreturns i dont need to pass nullable list. As per your suggestion just to get it compiling , changed the method to accept nullable value . While debugging i can see that the values are getting passed but the method returns null. Why is that so ?

Comment: public double? CompoundReturns(double?[] rtns)
        {
            if (rtns.Length == 0)
                return null;
            return rtns.Aggregate((double?)1, (acc, val) => acc * (1 + val)) - 1;
        }

Comment: @Tom: Because you're starting with a nullable value.  `.Mtd` is a nullable decimal.  Don't approach this from the perspective of trying to change keywords until the code compiles.  Approach it from the perspective of what logic you want to implement.  Your database *might* return `null` values for that column.  Do you want to support that or not?  Should the database column not allow nulls?  Should the query filter out nulls before performing the logic?  Should the logic support nulls?  It's your system, you have to decide what you want it to do.

Comment: I need the column to support null values

Comment: @Tom: You could update your call to `Aggregate()` to use `decimal?` instead of `decimal` then: `rtns.Aggregate((decimal?)1, (acc, val) => acc * (1 + val)) - 1;`

Comment: How is that different from what i shared earlier public double? CompoundReturns(double?[] rtns) { if (rtns.Length == 0) return null; return rtns.Aggregate((double?)1, (acc, val) => acc * (1 + val)) - 1; }

Comment: Did you mean change double to decimal as well

Comment: @Tom: Why a `double`?  I wouldn't recommend switching between `decimal` and `double` without specific reason, they handle numbers very differently.  In your original question all of the types are `decimal` (nullable or otherwise), so it's likely best to stick with that.  Just make them nullable where you need them to be.

Comment: The list of Mtd values that i am getting is of type double.

Comment: If i change the model entity to type decimal then i get an error Specified cast was invalid while executing             var benchMark1Returns = GetViewService<MV_INDEX_PERFORMANCE>().Where(x =>  x.IndexId == benchmark1 && x.PriceDate.Year == 2019).Select(x => x.Mtd).ToArray();

Comment: @Tom: Ok, then if you need to use `double` instead of `decimal` then go ahead and do that.  Update your method to accept and return `double` values instead of `decimal` values.  Regardless of the type you use, the overall point remains the same... Whatever the type is, you need to consistently use that type or meaningfully convert it to a different type.  You can't directly convert a nullable type to a non-nullable type.  Since you said you need to support null values, then the types need to consistently be nullable throughout the logic.

Comment: David my main problem is that the method is returning null. While debugging i can see that it executes return rtns.Aggregate((double?)1, (acc, val) => acc * (1 + val)) - 1;

Comment: So why is it returning null

Comment: How do i send a non nullable double array to the function. I think that might help

Comment: I basically fixed it by  var benchMark1Returns = GetViewService<MV_INDEX_PERFORMANCE>().Where(x => x.Mtd != null && x.IndexId == benchMark1 && x.PriceDate.Year == year).Select(x => x.Mtd).ToArray();
            
            double[] temp1 = benchMark1Returns.Cast<double>().ToArray();

            var compoundReturnsBenchMark1 = CompoundReturns(temp1);

Answer (score 2):

When you call `new { x.Mtd }`, you are instructing the compiler to create a new, anonymous type which as a single property, called `Mtd`, which contains the decimal value. Naturally, this isn't a `decimal[]`, it's a `MyType[]`.

Since it doesn't seem like you're actually using that anonymous type for anything, you should simply return the decimal value itself, instead of the anonymous type:

`.Select(x => x.Mtd)`

Comment: I did as what you said but  the list contain null values and hence returns decimal array. Now the error message that i am getting is cannot convert decimal? [] to decimal[]

Answer (score 1):

`.Select(x => new { x.Mtd})` create a new anonymous object. You just want the property value:

```
.Select(x => x.Mtd)
```

If `Mtd` can be null and you wish to filter out the null values, use this:

```
.Where(x => x.Mtd != null).Select(x => x.Mtd.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: I did as what you said but  the list contain null values and hence returns decimal array. Now the error message that i am getting is cannot convert decimal? [] to decimal[]

Comment: That seems odd. Do you mean the data type of `Mtd` is wrong? Or is `decimal[] rtns`? If you just want to cast `decimal` to `decimal?`, then cast the value.

Comment: Filter out the null values, then cast.

Comment: @Amy That was exactly what I was typing :)

Comment: But how does checking null avoid the error as I still get the compile time error at this statement CompoundReturns(benchMark1Returns)

Comment: You should be more specific. `var benchMark1Returns` is of type `decimal[]` now, right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make two changes:

First remove anonymous type. Then for select

```
.Select( x=> x.Mtd ?? 0);
```

This will allow you to pass decimal[] as paramter without changing the current method.

Else, you have to do:

```
 .Select(x =x.Mtd)
```

And change the method parameter to have nullable decimal array.
Hope it is ok

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my earlier comment, viz

> assuming `x.Mtd` is `decimal`, then just remove the `new {}` i.e. `(x => x.Mtd).ToArray()`

The bigger problem though is that your database has nulls in it, when it really shouldn't - the consequences of a `null` index performance in a for a period in a compound returns chart would be catastrophic for the compound returns - a missing data point would invalidate all future data points.

So the real solution is to find any null datapoints in the data source and provide the correct data for them.

Then change the data type of `Mtd` on the Dto returned from `GetViewService` from

```
 decimal? Mtd
```

to

```
decimal Mtd
```

(i.e. disallow nulls).

Then all that is needed to your original code is to remove the anonymous class projection, i.e.

```
.Where(x => x.Mtd != null)
.Select(x => x.Mtd.Value)
.ToArray();
```